# Get All Members from a Guild in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hey this is my following code and it works, but I only get the users with whom I chatted(in private chat) once.

```
@client.command()
async def hi(ctx):
    with open('users.txt','w') as f:
        for member in ctx.guild.members:
            print("{},{}".format(member,member.id), file=f,)
        print("done")
```

Answer (score 4):

You might need to call [`fetch_members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.fetch_members) to update the clients internal cache from the Discord API:

```
@client.command()
async def hi(ctx):
    with open('users.txt','w') as f:
        async for member in ctx.guild.fetch_members(limit=None):
            print("{},{}".format(member,member.id), file=f,)
    print("done")
```

Comment: it worked but i had to change ``` guild.fetch_members``` to ```ctx.guild.fetch_members```
And then I will get this error and I have to reverificate my email: ```discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Intents enabled, if not, enable them and try.